# Problema com .htaccess

Tags: php, htaccess

Bom dia, peguei um site para dar uma trabalhada em cima dele.

Uso o easyphp e não consigo abrir nenhuma página do site no localhost (apenas deste site)

Acredito que possa ser o arquivo .htaccess que redireciona os links digitados. Por exemplo. Quando digito **localhost:8080/fenpor/aprendoemcasa.com.br/index.php** para abrir a página ele redireciona para **https://www.localhost:8080/index.php**

Aqui vai a parte do arquivo .htaccess que faz isso

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]   
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Tentei desativar essa função de troca de links passando para off o RewriteEngine.

```
RewriteEngine off
```

Porém ao fazer isso o seguinte erro acontece:

[image: Erro]

Encontrei onde o **DOCROOT** está sendo definido e a linha está assim.

```
define ('__DOCROOT__', '/home/fenpor/aprendoemcasa.com.br');
```

Porém este é o caminho que veio do backup, e sinceramente não faço a menor ideia de como mexer com .htaccess ou mesmo esse tal de DOCROOT. Alguém por favor pode ajudar? Estou a dias tentando visualizar pelo menos uma página do site e não consigo. E também não encontro solução na internet. Qual é o caminho correto que devo colocar ali na definição do DOCROOT? Se colocar o caminho correto meu problema será resolvido? Muito obrigado desde já

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido de forma simples no fim das contas.

Mudei no arquivo .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine off
```

fui na pasta de arquivos do apache, que se encontra nos arquivos do easyphp, e abri o arquivo **httpd.conf**. La dentro pesquiso pela palavra **DocumentRoot**

e consigo descobrir o caminho exato para o arquivo DocumentRoot.

No arquivo connection, coloco o caminho correto do DocumentRoot que foi encontrado no **httpd.conf**.

```
define ('__DOCROOT__', 'CAMINHO-CORRETO');
```

resolvido!